# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') error

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-development-server

This code is more likely referenced to the yt i watched since im still a newbie in web developing(front-end). I am building a sidebar but my js returns the message from the title I mentioned "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')".

```js
const sidenavbtn_menu = document.querySelector('sidenavbtn_menu');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('sidebar');
sidenavbtn_menu.onclick = function() {
    sidebar.classList.toggle('open')
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>wRBMS</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!---CSS Link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home_dashboard.css" type="text/css">
    <!---MATERIAL CDN Google-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="sidebar" id="">
            <div class="logo-contents">
                <div class="logo">
                <img href="#">
                <div class="logo-name">w<span>RBMS</span></div>
                </div>
                <span class="material-symbols-sharp" id="sidenavbtn_menu">menu</span>
            </div>
           
            <ul class="sidenav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="material-symbols-sharp">home</i>
                        <span>Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="material-symbols-sharp">monitoring</i>
                        <span>MFO</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
               
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </div>    
    [enter image description here][1]
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `const sidenavbtn_menu = document.querySelector('sidenavbtn_menu');` => `const sidenavbtn_menu = document.querySelector('.sidenavbtn_menu');`. Same goes for the other used in your project. `querySelector` expects a dot (.) for classes, a hashtag (#) for ID's and nothing for tags (div / html / etc)

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in the following lines:

```js
const sidenavbtn_menu = document.querySelector('sidenavbtn_menu');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('sidebar');
```

`document.querySelector()` needs a css-like selector-string. If you want the Selector to match the ID-Field, you need to add `#` at the beginning. `document.querySelector('#sidenavbtn_menu')`

If you want to match the class field `document.querySelector('.CLASS_VALUE')`

More Information are found here:
[CSS-Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

But i would suggest to use the method `document.getElementById('sidenavbtn_menu')` as it is more optimized for this scenario.

Comment: Upvoted your answer because you mentioned that `querySelector` is slower. Verified this and it turns out to be 99.35% slower. Didn't know that and I think that's actually valuable information. All other answers should've just been "close votes for simple typographical error"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify if it is a class or id using `.` for class and `#` for id.

```js
const sidenavbtn_menu = document.querySelector('#sidenavbtn_menu');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
sidenavbtn_menu.onclick = function() {
    sidebar.classList.toggle('open')
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>wRBMS</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!---CSS Link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home_dashboard.css" type="text/css">
    <!---MATERIAL CDN Google-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="sidebar" id="">
            <div class="logo-contents">
                <div class="logo">
                <img href="#">
                <div class="logo-name">w<span>RBMS</span></div>
                </div>
                <span class="material-symbols-sharp" id="sidenavbtn_menu">menu</span>
            </div>
           
            <ul class="sidenav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="material-symbols-sharp">home</i>
                        <span>Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="material-symbols-sharp">monitoring</i>
                        <span>MFO</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
               
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </div>    
    [enter image description here][1]
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `document.querySelector` you have to specify if it's an id, class or else. Ex : `document.querySelector('#sidenavbtn_menu');`, you could also use `document.getElementById('sidenavbtn_menu');`

`document.querySelector('.sidebar');` will return the first element of the array of elements having `.sidebar`. If you want to select all elements with a class you could do `document.querySelectorAll(".someClass").forEach((e) => {e.doSomething();});`

Comment: still dont work, i think I will just build a new sidebar from scratch again. Thank you

Comment: @Rax22 if you console.log `document.querySelector('.sidebar')` or `document.querySelector('#sidenavbtn_menu')` it should return your elements, so your problem should be somewhere else now